# Serverless DDNS in an "AWS Like" cloud?

Tags: amazon-web-services, high-availability, ddns

I am on a closed network, usin a derivative of AWS. I have one VPC in 2 Availability Zones, with a small range of IPs. Many of my VMs have dynamically assigned IPs.

Right now, my Puppet Master is in AZ-A and serving as the DDNS server. I need to make this server a Multi-AZ solution.

**Question:** How can I have all my VMs resolve the IP address of my Puppet Master after it restarts with a different IP address?

**Relavent Details:**
I do not have a large enough IP space to create an ELB.
Route 53 is *not* available.
Lambda is *not* available.
My Puppet Master *can* be configured to always have the same host name.
Expanding my IP space is not a workable option.
Puppet HA is not available to me.

Please feel free to migrate to another forum if this is not the right place to ask the question.

Comment: What is "a derivative of AWS"?

Comment: @MichaelHampton, he probably can't tell you but I'd assume it's something like GovCloud.

Comment: Given the apparently tiny IP space, could you script something to regularly look for a Puppet master in the available range?

Comment: @duct_tape_coder If it was GovCloud, he would be able to tell us, and virtually everything applicable to AWS would also apply.

Comment: A Derivative of AWS means that it is the same type of cloud as AWS, but built and paid for by a private entity. GovCloud is a good example of an AWS derivative. It also means that all the "niceities" on AWS may not be available (like Route 53).